# Nuget scripting in VS 2017

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

I want to add a custom install script for my VS 2017 NuGet package.

Problem is, support for the [install.ps1/uninstall.ps1](https://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html) mechanism was removed. init.ps1 still works, but it would run every time the solution is opened, and that is unacceptable (it's a potentially lengthy process).

I read it's possible to define custom msbuild targets in the build dir, but I cannot get that to work because it requires manipulating the .nuspec file to include the files, and I can't see how to do that in VS 2017 with just the .csproj file.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve using the custom script?

Comment: Bring in a native dll which the package p/invokes. I do it using [the Conan package manager](conan.io), which abstracts me from all the OS/compiler/arch stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I cannot get that to work because it requires manipulating the .nuspec file to include the files

You can use the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/downloads/get/clickOnce/NuGetPackageExplorer.application) to add custom msbuild `.targets` in the `build` directory without manipulating the .nuspec file:

[image]

> I can't see how to do that in VS 2017 with just the .csproj file.

As you know, **Powershell script support was modified to no longer execute install and uninstall scripts**, so we could not custom install scripts that is called when installing the nuget package, otherwise, we need to overwrite the NuGet API in visual Studio: [IVsPackageInstaller interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/nuget-api-in-visual-studio#ivspackageinstaller-interface)(Not recommended).

So as a workaround, we could use define custom msbuild .targets file to achieve what you want achieve by the custom install script after install the nuget package. For example, you want custom install nuget script to change the default dll output, you can use a .target file with copy task to achieve it, you can create a file build\MyNuGet.targets containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <MySourceFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)MyFolder\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="MyNuGetCustomTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. Details here: https://programatealgo.blogspot.com.ar/2017/11/nuget-scripting-in-vs-2017.html